# ASP MVC 5.2 using nested dictionaries for htmlAttributes in EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to pass a nested Dictionary into the EditorFor viewData.

```
@{
    var viewData = new RouteValueDictionary();
    var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
    htmlAttributes.Add("title", "foo");
    viewData["htmlAttributes"] = htmlAttributes;
}
Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty, viewData);
```

The problem is that the tile="foo" does not get rendered.
When I'm using

```
var htmlAttributes = new {title = "foo"};
```

everything is working as expected.

I need htmlAttributes to be a Dictionary, because in my application it is dynamically generated.

So how can I pass a Dictionary in there.
I already tried to pass in thmlAttributes as an ExpandoObject, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible (MVC 5.2) see this Bug:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1736

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it not possible to do, at least not the easy way cuz the EditorFor creates many html elements and therefor it's not clear on which element the htmlAttributes should apply.

However, the hard way is to implement your own Object.cshtml in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml. Following is an example of custom Object.cshtml (bootstrap specific) where you can grab values from ViewData and construct the output Html anyway you like.

```
@using MvcApplication1.Utility
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} else {
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {
        var htmlString = prop.IsReadOnly ? Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) : Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName);
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            @htmlString
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = Html.ValidationErrors(prop);
            <div class="form-group @(prop.IsReadOnly ? "form-group-readonly" : "") @(errors.Any() ? "has-error has-feedback" : "")">
                <label class="control-label" for="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(prop.PropertyName)">@prop.GetDisplayName()</label>
                @htmlString
                @foreach (var err in errors)
                {
                    <div class="field-validation-error">@err.ErrorMessage</div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

and the utility functions

```
    public static IEnumerable<ModelError> ValidationErrors<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
    {
        string modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(modelMetadata.PropertyName);
        return ValidationErrors(htmlHelper, modelName);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ModelError> ValidationErrors<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        return ValidationErrors(htmlHelper, String.Empty);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ModelError> ValidationErrors(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String modelName)
    {
        FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext;
        if (formContext == null)
            yield break;

        if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName))
            yield break;

        ModelState modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        if (modelState == null)
            yield break;

        ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = modelState.Errors;
        if (modelErrors == null)
            yield break;

        foreach(var err in modelErrors)
            yield return err;
    }
```

Comment: In this case I'm using it for a simple string property which should render as Textbox. And since MVC 5.1 it is possible to add a Property "htmlAttributes" to the additionalViewData param which gets rendered as html attributes. So this should not be the problem.

Comment: In that case use Html.TextBoxFor instead

Comment: But I would like to use it on EditorFor, because that way i can also use my own Template which might contain of 2 TextBoxes. When using EditorFor, that "htmlAttributes" will be written into the ViewData and automatically be picked up by all Textboxes on that custom template.

Comment: It just doesnt work that way it you are using EditorFor, please read my answer carefully